# Mongoose find() not show my output in console.log

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, find

I am working on a project with node, express, mongo and I am trying to query all my topics out of the db.

I believe my code is correct but when I run the app in de browser my console.log does not show my output.

This is my code of my route:

```
// show all topics 
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

var db = req.db;
console.log('Loggin DB: ' + db);

Topic.find({}).exec(function(err, topics)
{
    if(err)
    {
        return next(err)
        console.log("Logging the error: " + err);
        console.log('There were no topics based on your current location');
     }
     else
     {
        console.log('Whoop whoop we found topics near your location');
        //renders the data on the page
        res.render('index', { topic : topic } );
        console.log("Logging data: " + topic);
        console.log("Logging data title: " + topic.topicTitle);
     }
});
});
```

Comment: If there is an error, the `return` will prevent you from ever getting to `console.log`

Comment: thats the thing there is no error

Comment: @GY22 "I believe my code is correct" - it is not correct

Comment: @Dyrk, if its not correct. Is it possible to point me in the right direction ...

Comment: You are returning `topics` in your `find` callback function, but you're passing `topic` to the render function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are gettin topic**s**

```
Topic.find({}).exec(function(err, topics)
```

And then you are using topic (it is not exists)

```
res.render('index', { topic : topic } );
    console.log("Logging data: " + topic);
    console.log("Logging data title: " + topic.topicTitle);
```

Comment: thanks for that. i overlooked the typo. but its still not logging my console.logs ...

Answer (score 1):

You are using console.log on the server side. That will not be shown client side in the browser, but rather in the command prompt/terminal where you are running node js.